# Call jQuery for each row

Tags: php, jquery, jqmodal

I want to make a link to call for each row.

Here is the code:

```
foreach($docs as $row) {
echo "<td><h5><a href='' id='onclick' class='onclickcalldocEdit_".$row->dId."'>".$row->dName."</a></h5></td>";
echo "<div id='response_proj' class='container_proj_".$row->dId."'>
/* container code here */
}
```

So, basically I create a container for each row and name differs only by id.
I've used this script to try to get it work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var className = $('#onclick').attr('class');
    var contName = $('#response_proj').attr('class');
    $(className).jqm({trigger:contName, toTop: true});
});
</script> ";
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit about what you want to do?

Comment: I have a container, which I call when click on a link. I want to call the same container for each value I am using. If I use only one container it works great, but when I try to make a container for each row I can't get it working.

Comment: What does "call the same container" mean?

Comment: It Mean that I want to use the same container, only with different values (that's why I use for each).

Comment: With the limited information you have given, check out jQuery's append, prepend, appendTo, etc. If that doesn't help, please present more information about how you intend to populate the container with information. Are you using information inside the $row object for populating the container?

Comment: @Juzt1s there is a basic problem with your initial loop since you use the same `id` for all the different HTML `div` and `a`. Having all the same `id` does not allow  jQuery to select them -all- since `id` must be unique. Since an HTML element might have multiple `class` attributes, I do recommend using `onclick` and `response_proj` as part of the class and then select them by using jQuery class selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#onclick").each(function(){
    var className = this.attr('class');
    var contName = this.closest('td').next('#response_proj').attr('class');
    $(className).jqm({trigger:contName, toTop: true })
  })
})
```

Frankly speaking, I think the better way is to use data-id and class attributes(without id):

```
<a href='' class='onclick' data-id='".$row->dId."'>".$row->dName."</a>
```

And access id via

```
var id = $('.onclick').data('id');
```